# Linq To Entities - Filter on list

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm really battling to utilize some form of filter method for some particular data. Filtering on Device (see class below) without worrying about filtering on the child `List<DeviceQueue>` works perfectly as expected. However when I attempt to filter on say MessageId and/or SequenceId the result returns all the entries in the MessageQueue table, ignoring my filter.

See Data.Model for Device :

```
public class Device : EntityBase
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; } 
    public virtual List<DeviceQueue> MessageQueue { get; set; }
}
```

See Data.Model for DeviceQueue :

```
public class DeviceQueue : EntityBase
{
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public Int32 SequenceId { get; set; }
```

See Filter Method (updated following 1st suggested answer) :

```
        public IQueryable<Device> Filter(IQueryable<Device> device)
    {

        IQueryable<DeviceQueue> deviceQueue = Enumerable.Empty<DeviceQueue>().AsQueryable();

        //Because it is IQueryable, the data is not fetched until you bind it so it only pulls the data you need.
        if (DeviceId != null)
        {
            device = device.Where(d => d.Id == DeviceId);
        }

        if (SequenceId != null)
        {
            device = device.Where(d => d.MessageQueue.Any(q => q.SequenceId == SequenceId.Value));
        }

        if (MessageId != null)
        {
            device = device.Where(d => d.MessageQueue.Any(q => q.MessageId == MessageId));
        }

        return device;
    }
```

Comment: You don't tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My bad, missing info indeed. See now :) thanks :)

Comment: Still not clear. You don't have to put your real project here, instead, put a **minimal** demo.

Comment: Sorry It was very late when posted this. I will reword my post and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a predicate as follows:

```
 if (SequenceId.HasValue)
 {
     device = device.Where(d => d.MessageQueue
                        .Any(q => q.SequenceId == SequenceId.Value));
 }
```

Same with `MessageId`.

Comment: Thanks for the post, all works great at design time and no errors, however my result shows that its not using the sequenceId as a filter. Its returning all the messagequeue items for that device.

Comment: Marking this as the answer. My understanding of Any() was incorrect.